# Microsoft Cognitive Face API

Tags: face-detection, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have a need to consume Azure FACE API. But it is still not available in India. However If I host my application in some US servers like AWS. Will I be able to consume the API?

Answer (score 0):

There are no *technical* reasons preventing you from using servers in a given region.  Different geographic zones exist primarily to reduce latency.  If your images are stored in the US, you may very well be better off using Microsoft Cognitive Services hosted in the US.